# How to execute a Parallels Windows application with command line parameters from Mac?

Tags: command-line, parallels-desktop

I am trying to call Beyond Compare Windows app to perform a file compre directly from Mac but I am block with command line argument passing.

You can call Windows applications from the OS X command line via something like:

```
open "$HOME/Applications (Parallels)/{ca50aac6-caa6-47a6-9bfe-e38f6261cb8d} Applications.localized/python.exe.app" --args -v
```

Still, it seems that there is a problem when you try to pass arguments.

Answer (score 4):

**APPROACH 1**

This approach is a hack, but works with the least expensive version of Parallels.

On the virtual Windows machine:

- Create a *.bat file for each possible set of parameters. For example:

```
     @echo off
     start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApplication.exe" --myArg
     exit
```

On the Mac:

- Navigate to `$(HOME)/Applications (Parallels)/VMNAME` Applications, where VMNAME is the name of a virtual machine.
- Duplicate the *MyApplication.app* application bundle and rename the duplicate *MyApplication --arg.app*.
- Right-click *MyApplication --myArg.app* and choose "Show Package Contents*.
- Open Contents/Resources/AppParams.pva in an editor (e.g., TextEdit), and change the value of the `App Path` property to the absolute path in the virtual machine to the *.bat file, rather than the application. Save the file.

This is similar to @johnl's answer above, which provided the vital clue. However, at least in Parallels 11, the `App Path` property would only work with an application path, not with a command line.

**APPROACH 2**

As of Parallels 11, this approach requires one of the more expensive editions of Parallels - Pro or Business. I don't have either, and haven't tested this approach.

According to the Parallels manual [Parallels Desktop for Mac Pro Edition](http://download.parallels.com/desktop/v11/docs/en_US/Parallels%20Desktop%20Pro%20Edition%20Command-Line%20Reference.pdf), the command `prlctl exec` can accept a command to be executed on the Windows virtual machine.

> **prlctl exec**
>
> Executes a command inside a virtual machine. Parallels Tools must be installed in a virtual machine to use this utility. Commands in Linux guests are invoked with `bash -c`.
>
> Syntax
>
> `prlctl exec vm_id|vm_name command`
>
> **Parameters**
>
> Name Description
>
> *vm_id|vm_name* The UUID or the name of the virtual machine.
>
> *command* A command to execute.

Comment: I like the sound of approach 2 but it doesn't work for me on my Windows 10 VM. I can `exec ... cmd.exe` (but this starts an interactive shell in the host terminal, it doesn't open cmd up inside the guest). If I try something like `exec ... notepad.exe` then nothing happens at all.

Comment: @cdlk - I'm not able to test this approach myself. In your case, did you start the command with `prlctl`? Do you have Parallels 11 with the Pro or Business edition?

Comment: No worries. I'm actually evaluating the trial version of Parallels Pro 11 at the moment. I contacted Parallels support earlier on (re. `exec` on Windows VMs) and they pointed me towards approach 1 instead, so I guess this isn't supported on Windows. Out of interest, on OSX VMs, I can run `prlctl exec ... open /Applications/Notes.app/` and this opens the notes app in the guest as you'd expect.

Comment: Unfortunately Parallels' prlctl does not seem to allow passing command line arguments or setting environment variables in the guest app, without kluges such as placing such things in a file to pass across the Host/Guest boundary.    By comparison, VirtualBox makes this easy to do:  `VBoxManage guestcontrol start [--exe] [--putenv][--unquoted-args]`. More and more I regret having chosen Parallels rather than VirtualBox.

Answer (score 1):

this is a neat hack to get parameters passed to your windows applications:

http://forum.parallels.com/threads/batch-files.11285/

The salient pieces:

1. copy and rename the `Windows Command Processor.app` application bundle in your Parallels Applications directory. (should be in `~/Applications (Parallels)/{<GUID>} Applications.localized`).
2. edit `Renamed Windows Command Processor.app/Contents/Resources/AppParams.pva`and change the `App Path` property to `...\cmd.exe /C <path-to-windows-executable> <parameters>`

Comment: Thanks for this.  I *think* that this means that the `<parameters>` need to be hardwired in the `AppParams.pva` file.  Is there any way to pass these from the MacOS environment or command line?   I.e. to have a MacOS script (e.g. bash) take command line parameters that it passes across Parallels to a script in the Windows guest?  (Apart from modifying the `.app` bundle or the `AppParams.pva` file on the fly, which is annoying to make MP safe; generating is MP safe, but leaves garbage that mist be cleaned up.)

Comment: I vaguely remember this working when I first started using Parallels circa 2 years ago in 2015 - editing the .app bundle `AppParams.pva` and changing the command.   Not enough for me to really start using it.  But working enough that I thought it might eventually be made to work.   //   Unfortunately, now, in 2017, 2 years later and several updates of Parallels and MacOS, it works not at all.  In fact, when I do such edits, even just adding a single blank character after `cmd.exe` fails - when I run such a bundle, it gets deleted !!!  // Probably some security feature, but I am stymied.

Comment: As described in stackoverflow.com/questions/41456329/… I have switched to using VirtualBox for automation, because because I was not able to get any form of parameterized automation of GUI apps running across Parallels. But I would love to get automation across Parallels working, since Parallels does some things better than VirtualBox.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a while trying to implement the solution 1 here, and then found an alternative with the latest Parallels.

Any file with a cmd extension gets executed in the Parallels Windows VM (VBS files too)

So you can create a cmd file with START and your parameters (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154075/using-the-start-command-with-parameters-passed-to-the-started-program ) and use

```
open TheCreatedFile.cmd
```

to execute it.