# Parallels Desktop: Run windows application with command line arguments

Tags: macos, windows, virtualization, parallels-desktop

I'm running on MacOS with Sierra and I have a Windows VM running on Parallels 12.

I want to run an application that is installed on the Windows VM and I want to run it with arguments, in the same way that I can do it on Windows with cmd.

An example: I have an app in Windows VM called bestApp.exe that need two arguments like "bestApp.exe -r "C:\PathFolder\"

Looking on internet I found something [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/100574/how-to-execute-a-parallels-windows-application-with-command-line-parameters-from). The answer is quite old and I'm interested on the second approach but seems that I need the Pro version of Parallels to try it.

My question is: how I can run my app, on Windows-Parallels, from Mac with arguments? That approach is valid and, also, it is the only one?

EDIT: I found that I can open a Windows app from Mac running the "open" command on terminal but if I use "--args" to pass arguments it doesn't work...

Example. "open myApp.exe --args -blabla" open my app on VM but without arguments

Answer (score 1):

Install, configure and launch [Bitvise SSH Server](https://www.bitvise.com/getting-started-install-ssh-server) (Personal Edition is [free](https://www.bitvise.com/ssh-server-usage-faq#personal-edition) but has some restrictions compared to the licensed server) in the Windows VM.

Launch Terminal on the OS X host, ssh to the ssh server and execute any command required.

---

I also tried [PowerShell](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell) which allows Win2Win remote access [after enabling](http://www.howtogeek.com/117192/how-to-run-powershell-commands-on-remote-computers/) it on the hosts, but the OS X version still lacks this feature.

Comment: Mmm maybe can be a solution. I hope there is something else more simple...